# Big-O of Fibonacci with memoization?

Tags: python, big-o, time-complexity, memoization

When I ran this program it seemed to be O(1) because it was almost for pretty large numbers for fib without memoization. If it is calculating the previous numbers then all it has to do is add and it has the result which would be O(1)?

```
memo = {}
def Fib(n):
    if (n < 2):
        return 1
    if not n in memo:
        memo[n] = Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)
    return memo[n]
```

I also timed it compared to a fibonacci program without memoization and here was the plot result from 1 to 40: 
[image]

Comment: You can't compute Fibonacci numbers in constant time. The cost of computing and storing the memorized values is part of the cost.

Comment: Try plotting with 1000 elemenets.

Comment: I think there's an error in your data.

Comment: @erip how? i didn't plot it myself it was done with gnuplot and the times were recorded with time.time()

Comment: Because 0 time doesn't really exist in computation.

Comment: There is no error in the data -- it is a function of the magnitude of the numbers

Comment: It is generally faster to look up a saved reference than to perform an increasingly large number of computations, yes.

Comment: What plots as 0 in the diagram would be something more like 0.00001

Comment: Maybe a better question to ask than to jump to conclusions like wrong data: what are the y axis units? `sec`? `msec`? `years`?

Comment: @erip y = time in sec, x = input fib(x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the lower bound of your algorithm is `O(n)` simply because for a given `n` you fill a dictionary with `n` values (that's assuming we are dealing with first call to `Fib`).

On the other hand for each `n` every operation you do inside `Fib` function is `O(1)` amortized. So all in all you get that **first call** to `Fib` is `O(n)` amortized.

Note that for huge `n` this might go above `O(n)` because `not in` operation is not `O(1)` (it is only `O(1)` amortized). How huge `n` has to be? Don't know, depends on the underlying hashing function. Plus you may run out of memory before you reach such `n`.

Now this is obviously at the cost of space (i.e. memory) which becomes `O(n)` as well. And this is only under the assumption that each integer takes the same amount of space which unfortunately is not true for Python. The consequence of "no limit for integers" approach is that big integers are kept in memory as an array of digits. Since a number `n` has at most `log_b(n)+1` digits (where `b` is numerical system, e.g. `10` for decimal system, I'm not sure which Python uses internally) we get that real space complexity is somewhere between `O(n)` and `O(log_b(n!))`.

The thing becomes more complicated if we don't care whether it is a first call or not. But only a bit. You can easily check tha generally `Fib` is `O(max(n-k, 1))` complexity, where `k` is the size of `memo` dictionary at the time of the call.

Compare it to for example iterative method. In that method you always keep 2 last elements and a counter. That way you get `O(n)` time complexity and `O(1)` space complexity.

Of course for the naive recursive Fibonacci the time complexity is `O(2^n)` with `O(n)` space complexity (due to call stack).

Comment: _Of course for the naive recursive Fibonacci the time complexity is O(2^n) with O(1) space complexity._ It's actually `O(n)` space because of the stack from recursive calls. There is no tail recursion optimization.

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that it is still O(n), say you calculate Fin(100), you will need to calculate all the numbers before getting 100. Sure if a previous run has been done, then you will have it in memory, but for any number you can imagine and had run a previous execution, I can imagine a bigger one :)

Maybe you could say it is O(1) amortized (same as it is O(1) for an ArrayList in java to get an element... in reality it is O(n) as you might need to resize the array, but normally that is not the case, so O(1) is an "acceptable" measure).